# how to retrieve the contact list in android with name and phone number only

Tags: android, list, cursor, contacts

i am using the following code

```
public static void getaAllContacts() {
    sContentResolver = sContext.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = sContentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String sName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            new DBHelper(sContext).addToContacts(sName);
        }
}
```

the problem is my phone has only 4 contacts but it is displaying more contacts from what i have in my phone. i dont know from where is that coming. i want only the contacts that are in my contact list in the contacts app in my phone

Comment: so, it must be showing you some email addresses also?

Comment: yes it is showing me some email addresses also

Comment: put your cursor in class scope rather than within the scope of a method.

Comment: done that , no difference same error is there

Comment: also if a person has multiple numbers i want to store all the numbers

Comment: why dont u try and delete the app and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
    };
    String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";
    Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
```

This will return only those contacts which has phone numbers.

To get contacts phone number:

```
       String phoneNumber = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
       Log.i("Number", phoneNumber);
```

Comment: nops not working im getting this   'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.'

Comment: Use 'cursor.moveToFirst()' before using this

Comment: make contacts class scope Cursor variable. Its not a good practice but its a hot fix.

Comment: i dont get it, how would i do that?